# Can flux pinning be used for propulsion in Earth's magnetic field?

Tags: superconductivity, space-travel

I was wondering if the following steps would result in a net displacement on a spacecraft operating in Earth's magnetic field:

1. Turn on a superconductor
2. Use a linear actuator to shift some mass
3. Turn off the superconductor
4. Shift the mass back to its original position
5. Repeat

Would flux pinning allow pushing or pulling against the field?

Comment: You can do it without shifting mass. Remember you're moving around at 8 km/s. A related question on SEx.SE: [Preventing orbital decay and micro adjustments to orbits by “leaning on Earth's magnetic field"](http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/778/preventing-orbital-decay-and-micro-adjustments-to-orbits-by-leaning-on-earths)

Comment: I assume that magnetic forces due to a charge in a field and flux pinning would be different.  Are they essentially the same or highly correlated?

Comment: @DeerHunter It sounds like you're talking about using plain old Lorenz forces rather than flux pinning.